# Use Google Map API in Bootstrap collapse div

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I know there are a lot of subject about it but I can't make it work.

I have a working Google Map on everywhere in my website but not the a collapse div that open when I click on a button.
It just displays a gray map.

I'm using a simple map like :

```
function initMap(){
              geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
              var myLatLng = {lat: 48.8457746, lng: 2.2862185};
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapConseiller'), {
                zoom: 12,
                center: myLatLng,
                zoomControl: true,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                scaleControl: true,
                streetViewControl: false,
                rotateControl: false
              });
```

And I call this function here :

```
<script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyAPIKey&callback=initMap">
            </script>
```

Here is the code : https://jsfiddle.net/cm64aug0/

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I'm guessing that clicking the button shows the id (`mapConseiller`). If this is the case, then Maps won't be able to render the map. You should adjust your code so that the ID is created first then run the function when you click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution ! Actually you have to load the map just after the div is completely visible.

I can't trigger the event ('shown.bs.collapse') so I modify the Bootstrap.js to call the initMap() function after this element was triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already solved the issue, but you could just do the following (instead of changing the third party javascript file...

Assuming that you have a collapsed div like this:

```
<div id="mapConseiller" class="panel-body panel-collapse collapse in">
```

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mapConseiller').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
        initMap();
    });
}
```

This way, the map will be initialized only after the collapsed div is visible.